# Is it possible to grant only metadata privileges in MySQL

Tags: mysql, privileges

TLDR;

#### Target:

Is it possible to grant privileges to a certain "audit" user to access to MySQL metadata only (schema,table,column at least) without access to exact data in tables?

#### Version

MySQL 8+

#### Try:

Before this issues,

I've been already tried or known:

- review [MySQL official docs on privileges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html) (notice me if I missed the answer in it)
- search keywords on SOF: `mysql`, `privilege`, `metadata`, etc.
- find solutions with my DBA friends
- grant `show databases` to users, but it could get the schema lists only
- all grants to `infomatica_schema` was in vain, as known to all
- `SELECT ON *.*` is another answer, but my leader dont wanna data leak through it

#### Background:

My company ordered devops to collect MySQL metadata for some issues of audits or security monitoring or else (I don't know the details of whole story). Unnecessary data leak would not be expected to my leader.
BTW, I dont know the specific method where they, audit depts maybe, are going to collect metadata. All I've been required to do is to create a granted user for them.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a workaround for this, but it's kind of a hack, not a true solution.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-tables.html says:

> If you have no privileges for a base table or view, it does not show up in the output from SHOW TABLES or mysqlshow db_name.

That is, you can't use SHOW TABLES, or see the tables in queries against INFORMATION_SCHEMA (because SHOW TABLES is really just a query against those system views).

But the language of "no privileges" got me thinking. Is there a privilege that the user could have, but which does not allow reading or writing data?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html says:

> The permissible *priv_type* values at the table level are ALTER, CREATE VIEW, CREATE, DELETE, DROP, GRANT OPTION, INDEX, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT, SHOW VIEW, TRIGGER, and UPDATE.

How about `SHOW VIEW`? This would only allow viewing metadata, not querying a table or a view.

So I tried it:

```
mysql> create user 'auditor'@'%';
mysql> grant show view on test.* to 'auditor'@'%';
```

Then I logged in as that user, and tried it:

```
mysql> show grants;
+----------------------------------------------+
| Grants for auditor@%                         |
+----------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `auditor`@`%`          |
| GRANT SHOW VIEW ON `test`.* TO `auditor`@`%` |
+----------------------------------------------+

mysql> use test

mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| Accounts       |
| Bugs           |
| BugsProducts   |
| BugStatus      |
...
```

I could also view columns, etc.

To be clear, those are concrete tables, not views. But since my auditor user has more than no privileges on the tables (even an irrelevant privilege), it qualifies for purposes of letting them view metadata about the tables.

In MySQL 8.0.20, they added the `SHOW ROUTINES` privilege. Prior to that, you needed `SELECT` privilege to view the body of stored procedure or functions. But you didn't mention auditors viewing routines in your question.

Comment: Thanks, you read docs in depth!! I tried `SHOW DATABASES/VIEW ON *.*` in MySQL, it managed to visit schema/tables (`show databases/tables`, as well as `information_schema.schemata/tables`), but it didn't work for columns. `desc MY_TABLE` leads to requisite of `SELECT` privileges. The reason might be the same as `SHOW ROUTINES` cases despite not necessary in my corp. I'm conferring with audit dept to the final solution.

Comment: The solution is `grant references on *.* to 'xxx'@'%'`. It's odd I feel...

Comment: Yes, any solution is going to feel like "cheating" I'm afraid.